# How can I see which Column A entries do not appear in Column B?

Tags: excel, vba, match

I am trying to see which Column A entries are not in Column B and then print these entries in Column C, and the corresponding B entries in Column D.
This code keeps giving me "Run time error '13': Type mismatch".

[image]

```
Option Explicit

 Sub Test()

  Dim LR As Long, i As Long
  LR = 8

For i = 2 To LR
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A" & i), Range("B:B")) = 0 Then
    Debug.Print Range("A" & i)
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: why not use a vlookup instead ? this sounds like a case for it.

Comment: You've got the argument order within `CountIf` flipped. The first argument is the range, and the second is the criterion.

Comment: @BigBen thanks, spot on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

**Answer with  For Each Loop:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowC As Long
    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, cell

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Set rngA = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        Set rngB = .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

        For Each cell In rngA

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngB, cell) Then
            Else
                .Range("C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = cell.Value
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

**Answer with Arrays:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRowC As Long
    Dim arrA As Variant, arrB As Variant, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim strA As String, strB As String
    Dim Appears As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        arrA = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row))
        arrB = Application.Transpose(.Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row))

        For i = 1 To UBound(arrA)

            strA = arrA(i)

            Appears = False

            For y = 1 To UBound(arrB)

                strB = arrB(y)

                If strA = strB Then
                    Appears = True
                    Exit For
                Else
                    Appears = False
                End If
            Next y

            If Appears = False Then
                .Range("C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = arrA(i)
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Answer with Dictionaries:**

```
Sub tesqt()

    Dim dictA As Object, dictB As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim key As Variant

    Set dictA = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dictB = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        For Each cell In .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Not dictA.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                dictA.Add key:=cell.Value, item:=dictA.Count + 1
            End If
        Next

        For Each cell In .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
            If Not dictB.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                dictB.Add key:=cell.Value, item:=dictB.Count + 1
            End If
        Next

        For Each key In dictA.keys

            If Not dictB.Exists(key) Then
                 .Range("C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = key
            End If

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Results:

[image]